# Sqlalchemy+pyodbc for mysql and pd.to_sql() giving strange and inconsistent error

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to connect, read and write from a mysql db using odbc(ODBC is a requirement and I'll have to use it) in python. I am using sqlalchemy and pyodbc. I am able to connect to the db and read. But when I am trying to write, pyodbc is giving me strange errors. The code is given below.

```
params = urllib3.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};"
                                f"SERVER={host}:{port};"
                                f"DATABASE={db};"
                                f"UID={username};"
                                f"PWD={password};"
                                f"charset=utf8")
db_engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}")
connection = db_engine.connect()
# main_df is a pd.DataFrame() 
maindf.to_sql("mytable", connection, if_exists="append", index=False, chunksize=1000)
```

The Error is given below:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1685, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 713, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.31-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '4' at line 1 (1064) (SQLParamData)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/myusername/cx-index-score/nice_rpa/pipeline.py", line 17, in <module>
    uploader.split_upload(os.path.abspath(Path('./datasets')))
  File "E:\myusername\cx-index-score\nice_rpa\processandupload.py", line 163, in split_upload
    self.writetosandbox()
  File "E:\myusername\cx-index-score\nice_rpa\processandupload.py", line 216, in writetosandbox
    self.maindf.to_sql("nice_daily_update", self.connection, if_exists="append",
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2779, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 590, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1405, in to_sql
    raise err
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1397, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 831, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 748, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1200, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 313, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1389, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1748, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1929, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1685, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 713, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.31-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '33\x03@333333\x03@333333\x03@' at line 1 (1064) (SQLParamData)")
```

If you see the syntax error part, it is actually supposed to be a simple string, which is `utf-8`. The Databse encoding is 'latin1'. Interestingly, even though each time the data and the error are same, but the "wrong syntax" part always changes. once, it was '4', then it was '33\x03@333333\x03@333333\x03@' and it changes on each run, the input data is always same though.
I have exhausted all the other stackoverflow questions related to this topic I can find. Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with a DataFrame that will reproduce the issue? Something similar to [this code](https://pastebin.com/i8gBRJk9) (which works for me).

Comment: Hey. I have narrowed down the problem and turns out pandas is creating the problem, not pyodbc or sqlalchemy. I did connection.execute('A insert query', params) and it actually wrote to db.

Comment: Hey Grod. I re-wrote the question with new info here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67164247/how-to-make-pandas-to-sql-to-stop-encoding-parameters-while-using-odbc
I am not closing this question so that if anyone comes up with the same error, they can understand it is not a sqlalchemy or pyodbc error, but mostly pandas