# Unknown encoding while using df.to_sql() to write to MySQL using pyodbc

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I have created a connection to MySQL db using pyodbc and sqlalchemy. But when I use `pd.to_sql()` it is giving me an error. The error seems like pandas is trying to do some encoding. The parameter which is getting converted is string datatype and the DATABASE encoding is `latin-1`.
But when I did `connection.execute(insert query,params)` with the same connection, it is working fine.
Also, when I am using `pd.to_sql()` with a connection made with `sqlalchemy` and `mysqlconnector` it is working efficiently.

```
params = urllib3.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver};"
                                f"SERVER={host}:{port};"
                                f"DATABASE={db};"
                                f"UID={username};"
                                f"PWD={password};"
                                f"charset=utf8")
db_engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}")
connection = db_engine.connect()
# main_df is a pd.DataFrame(). It contains a long text field which is most of the time getting affected. 
# the error mostly come from this column. 
maindf = pd.DataFrame()
maindf['transcript'] = ['This is a sample 1', 'This is sample2']
maindf.to_sql("mytable", connection, if_exists="append", index=False, chunksize=1000)
```

The Error is given below:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1685, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 713, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.31-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '4' at line 1 (1064) (SQLParamData)")

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/myusername/cx-index-score/nice_rpa/pipeline.py", line 17, in <module>
    uploader.split_upload(os.path.abspath(Path('./datasets')))
  File "E:\myusername\cx-index-score\nice_rpa\processandupload.py", line 163, in split_upload
    self.writetosandbox()
  File "E:\myusername\cx-index-score\nice_rpa\processandupload.py", line 216, in writetosandbox
    self.maindf.to_sql("nice_daily_update", self.connection, if_exists="append",
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2779, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 590, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1405, in to_sql
    raise err
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1397, in to_sql
    table.insert(chunksize, method=method)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 831, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 748, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1200, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 313, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1389, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1748, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1929, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1685, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\nice_rpa\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 713, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.31-log]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '33\x03@333333\x03@333333\x03@' at line 1 (1064) (SQLParamData)")
```

If you see the syntax error part, it is actually supposed to be a simple string, which is `utf-8`. The Databse encoding is 'latin1'. Interestingly, even though each time the data and the error are same, but the "wrong syntax" part always changes. once, it was '4', then it was '33\x03@333333\x03@333333\x03@' and it changes on each run, the input data is always same though.

Do you know how to stop pandas to preprocess my params before sending it to db? If that is not possible, can you please suggest an alternate to write multiple columns (range in 1000s) efficiently?

Comment: @Parfait - `engine.connect()` returns a SQLAlchemy `Connection` object which is okay to pass to `.to_sql()`. `engine.raw_connection()` is what returns the DBAPI layer's connection object.

Comment: @Jihjohn - You might try using the `dtype=` argument to `.to_sql()` to see if you can alter the encoding behaviour.

Comment: @Gord Thompson - I tried it. I tried both `sqlalchemy.types.String` and 'VARCHAR' also with remaining columns appropriate dtype. But they are not solving the problem.

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce your issue with Python 3.7.8 (64-bit), SQLAlchemy 1.4.9, pandas 1.2.4, pyodbc 4.0.30, MySQL Connector/ODBC 8.00.18.00. and MySQL Server 5.6.13. Database and table defined with latin1 character set. Inserting text with latin1, utf8, and utf8mb4 characters does not make pandas throw an error, although the utf8* characters get saved to the database as question marks (as expected).

Comment: In my case, when I executed the same insert query directly, it is working fine. So I think the problem is not with odbc, pyodbc, sqlalchemy or mysql. The main problem I am facing is I can't find the root cause, the error part changes each time. What I understand is that, pandas do some encoding and db is rejecting that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong driver. The driver in the server was `MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver` and I was using in `MySQL ODBC 8.0 ANSI Driver`. That explains the weird encoding.

```
params = urllib3.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};"
                                f"SERVER={host}:{port};"
                                f"DATABASE={db};"
                                f"UID={username};"
                                f"PWD={password};"
                                f"charset=utf8")
db_engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={params}")
connection = db_engine.connect()
```